# Can someone show me a more efficient way to handle multiple text field delegates?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on a project where the user have 5 text fields to input data. 
The "Calculate" button calculates the required computations based on user input.
My solution is to create 5 IBOutlet UITextFields and connect them in an xib file. Each text field handle events based on input with the following code. Can someone show me a efficient way to solve the problem?

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

if(textField == self.numberOfNightsTF){
    self.numberOfNights = [self.numberOfNightsTF.text intValue];
    NSLog(@"The number of nights is set to %.d days", self.numberOfNights);

}
else if(textField == self.nightlyChargeTF){
    self.nightChargeCost = [self.nightlyChargeTF.text floatValue];
    NSLog(@"The cost of charge per night is set to %.2f$", self.nightChargeCost);
}

else if(textField == self.roomServiceTF){
    self.roomServiceCost = [self.roomServiceTF.text floatValue];
    NSLog(@"The additional room service cost is set to %.2f$", self.roomServiceCost);
}

else if(textField == self.telephoneTF){
    self.telephoneCost = [self.telephoneTF.text floatValue];
    NSLog(@"The additional telephone service cost for telephone is set to %.2f$", self.telephoneCost);
}
else if(textField == self.miscCostTF){
    self.miscCost = [self.miscCostTF.text floatValue];
    NSLog(@"The miscellaneous is now set to %.2f$", self.miscCost);
}
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
```

}

Comment: The title can be reworded but this question shows enough research and code to warrant staying open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real ineffiency in the way you've handled this already, it is as good an approach as any other.  The only real problem with this approach is that it leads to bloated ViewController classes when (this approach) is applied multiple times.

As you get more experience in object oriented environments you'll learn about MVC and the state variables you are modifying here will be properties of a model object rather than self (assuming this code is in someViewController) so the messages might be self.model.telephoneCost=.....  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions that would help to cleanup.

The simplest would be to use as switch statement in the current function you are using, which would help a bit with readability.

Another option would be to create a category which allows you to set callback blocks to fire when each delegate method is called. These are easy to write and some examples exist already on Github: [UITextField+Blocks](https://github.com/haaakon/UITextField-Blocks)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [BlocksKit](https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit) because it adds blocks support for a bunch of other classes as well, such as UIAlertView, KVO, etc.

If you want to go full on reactive style, [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) is a very comprehensive framework that also provides similar functionality.

BlocksKit is a lot more light-weight, and pretty easy to read if you're getting used to block style programming, whereas ReactiveCocoa requires a much bigger commitment due to its steep learning curve (but also provides some excellent features like @strongify and @weakify to assist with block retention issues).